# React Native App laggy on Iphone, but fast in simulator

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode, firebase, react-native

What could be the possible causes of the following behaviour?

My React-Native app runs smooth in the Xcode Ximulator, but starts to hang and be unresponsive on the device (when i archive it and use the release version). I have checked possible memory leaks, but there are none.
Are there possible problems with the release version in contrast to the development build?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the application directly on the device then it might be laggy.

Create a production build and install the same on device.

You can then check the difference in the performance.

Comment: The production build (release) is where the problum occurrs. When i connect the device and use it in development mode it runs fast.

Comment: Can you provide me the list of the points where you are using setState or forceUpdate.

Comment: I don't use forceUpdate in any component. What is your idea? I have too many places where I use setState to collect them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all console.log and other console.* calls. They can cause lag when there is no debugger to log to. You can use a babel plugin to do this for you: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console